# How to access GitLab API behind Okta?

Tags: api, oauth, gitlab, okta

I've been trying to access some info on a gitlab project through the API, but the gitlab instance is behind an Okta auth system and I am not sure how to do it.

I am able to go through the Okta auth process and get a token, but I can't find any documentation on how to use this token to authenticate with Gitlab.

Has anyone been through this and is willing to help me here?

Comment: what is the token you are getting? are you sure it's not SSO what is configured between Okta and GitLab?

Comment: It is SSO. Don't I still need an Okta token to call gitlab?

Comment: you do not, I bet. gitlab API access should be working with some sort of tokens. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html is an example. But better read their documentation on accessing APIs